# Start and stop actions are no longer supported to kill a startup service in Debian

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I wanted to stop a service and I always used the command `update-rc.d exim4 stop` (i.e. if I want to stop `exim4`).
Now I receive this message:

> update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported;
>   falling back to defaults Use of uninitialized value in string eq at
>   /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 390. update-rc.d: warning: start runlevel
>   arguments (none) do not match exim4 Default-Start values (2 3 4 5)
>   update-rc.d: warning: stop runlevel arguments (none) do not match
>   exim4 Default-Stop values (0 1 6)

So, that means the command is not availlable anymore ? How can I solve properly ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `systemd` maybe? Then you should get familiar with `systemctl`, I think. Like `systemctl disable ...`.

Comment: Yes, ok. But I'd like to understand why I received this behaviour